# how to call atadenoise function in ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

how to use atadenoise with source code by transplanting it to a video engine. Is there any example to call function "ff_atadenoise_init_x86" in "FFmpeg/libavfilter/atadenoise.h"

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [ffmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#atadenoise) "atadenoise" is a video filter. In your code you should use FFmpeg's [libavfilter](https://ffmpeg.org/libavfilter.html) API instead of calling "ff_atadenoise_init_x86" function, e.g. like in the [filtering_video.c example](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/filtering_video.c).

Comment: Thx for your answer. I have read the example "FFmpeg/doc/examples/filtering_video.c",but I cannot really understand how it works.Do I need to modify any configuration parameter to make it call atadenoise. Also I'd like to debug it in macOS step by step to delve into the code.

Comment: @hiter1996 I assumed you are building your own application that uses FFmpeg libraries. Am I correct?

Comment: That's right. And I'm trying to use atadenoise in ffmpeg to do video processing. But first of all I want to build ffmpeg only from source code and debug atadenoise using Clion or other IDE to research the algorithm.

Comment: Or we can contact by email -- 366366235@qq.com